# typeof object but not array

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am looking for a quick check to determine if a value is an object `{}` but not an array `[]`. I have written this:

```
function isPlainObject(input) {
   return !Array.isArray(input) && typeof input === 'object';
}
```

Is there a shorter check I can use to determine this?

Or are there other possible data structures that still checkout as `typeof` `'object'`?

Comment: Both an `Array` and `null` will return typeof 'Object'

Comment: @TrojanByAccident that is correct, and that is the problem :) although you mean 'object' not 'Object' :)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It is not quicker, but more precise, with a check for falsy values, like `null`, which is an object.

```
function isPlainObject(input) {
   return input && !Array.isArray(input) && typeof input === 'object';
}
```

Comment: yep this is definitely an improvement

Comment: Note that `Date`, `Map`, `Set`, `WeakMap`, and `WeakSet` (etc) also satisfy `typeof input === 'object'`. To check against those, you could add guards such as `!(input instanceof Set)`, or use @RobG's answer.

Answer (score 6):

If you want to check if an object is a "plain" object, i.e. inherits directly from *Object.prototype*, then you should check for that.

E.g. the following first tests if *value* has *Object* anywhere on it's prototype chain (and hence will not throw an error for *getPrototypeOf*), then checks if its immediate `[[prototype]]` is *Object.prototype*:

```js
function isPlainObject(value) {
  return value instanceof Object &&
         Object.getPrototypeOf(value) == Object.prototype;
}

// Some tests
[[1,2],         // Array
 {},            // Plain object
 null,          // null
 document.createElement('div'),  // host object
 function(){},  // function object
 console        // host objet
 ].forEach(function(value) {
      console.log(value + ': ' + isPlainObject(value));
 });
```

#### Edit

If you want to test that the input is some extended object but not a Function, etc. that is much less efficient, e.g. test against some list of objects that you want to avoid:

```js
function isJustObj(obj) {
  var notThese = [Function, Array, Date];
  if (obj instanceof Object) {
    return !notThese.some(function(o) {
      return obj instanceof o;
    });
  }
  return false;
}

function Foo(){}

var tests = {'Array: ':[],
             'Object: ' : {},
             'Foo instance:' : new Foo(),
             'Function: ' : function(){},
             'Date: ' : new Date(),
             'Host obj: ' : document.createElement('div')
};

Object.keys(tests).forEach(function(test) {
  console.log(test + isJustObj(tests[test]));
})
```

Note that this strategy sees if the value is some kind of Object, then tests whether it's an instance of a particular set of constructors. This list of things to exclude can become very large since it's not possible in any reasonable way to rule out host objects which, by their very nature, can be indistinguishable from built-in objects based on some general test (see [*Is there an environment-agnostic way to detect Javascript Host Objects?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8645685/is-there-an-environment-agnostic-way-to-detect-javascript-host-objects)).

E.g.

```
console.log instanceof Function // true
console instanceof Object       // true
isPlainObject(console)          // false
```

So you either check if Object.prototype is the immediate `[[Prototype]]` or create a long list of constructors to test against. That list will go out of date very quickly given the variety of host environments available and the freedom for implementors to extend it. Also, you need to test every member of the host object set before trying to use it as it may not exist for the particular host on which the code is running.

Comment: yeah sorry semantics, by plain object I just meant: not null, not an array, etc. I think this methology might fail if the prototype chain has been extended a few times..?

Answer (score 1):

Javascript arrays are considered objects so typeof will always be object in case of array.